# Is there any possibilities to read STEP file using three.js file?

Tags: javascript, three.js, cad, step

In three.js file there is an option for read stl file for generate 3d pcb component. But is there any possibilities for reading STEP file? step file also contains a 3d component information. Or is there any other possibilities for reading STEP file?

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is there any possibilities to read STEP file?

Comment: You could use Blender (perhaps combined with a plugin) to convert the STEP file into STL and then import that into Three http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Outdated/Resources/File_Formats

Answer (score 1):

While still valid, you can try GitHub project based on three.js and java-script, server is not needed, it is pure browser only. You just need newer browser with web-assembly support.

[github 3d mesh viewer webgl](https://github.com/3dmeshviewer/stepfileviewer)

[alternative site with sample](https://3dmeshviewer.github.io/stepfileviewer/)

Comment: Sadly the site where the needed `meshviewer.r4.js` file is hosted is down. Anyone has the file?

Answer (score -1):

You can read a STEP file into FreeCAD, convert the solid to a mesh, and then export it to STL.

Comment: STL file does not support color information where as step has the color information.